# How do I find whether a document on the web is semantically related to some other document?

Tags: semantic-web, semantic-markup, semantic-analysis

My question here is that given a `document d1 on the web and a document d2` how do I tell that d1 and d2 are semantically related. Are there some API's that can do some amount of natural language processing that might give me a hint as to d1 is a probably connected to d2.
I need it badly and uregently.Please Help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use special microformats. See more at http://microformats.org/

Simple example:

```
<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/" rel="license">cc by 2.0</a>
```

Rel-License is one of several microformats. By adding rel="license" to a hyperlink, a page indicates that the destination of that hyperlink is a license for the current page.

Answer (score 1):

For semantically relating documents you can use special vocabularies like SKOS and relate them in an ontology. Or you can use - as silex mentioned - microformats directly in your documents.

For natural language processing, there exist different tools like GATE which can extract information. But this is not a trivial task.

Perhaps you can refine what you want to do? Do you want to define which documents are related? Or do you want a software to find out which documents may be related?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into "[named entity extraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_entity_recognition)" i.e. natural language processing to extract likely entities that are common to both documents. These are generally people, places, events, times, organisations.

Take a look at OpenCalais http://www.opencalais.com/ for some real-world applications of this type of technology.